# How to assign the output of a Fetch call to a variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, fetch, variable-assignment

I try to connect the output of a Fetch call to my page variable, but I just cannot seem to do it.
Could you please check out the code underneath and help me out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrN4Q.png)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the async/await approach will solve your issues.

```
async outputvariable() {
  try {

     const response = await fetch('https://api2.online-conve', {
         method: 'GET',
         credentials: 'same-origin'
     });
      const rlt = await response.json();
      return rlt;
  } catch (error) {
   console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the surrounding function an async function, and then await the response.

```js
async function(){
    try{
        var outputVariable = await fetch("URL").text();
        // Use outputVariable
    } catch(e){
        console.log('error', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Won't work unfortunately. The Javascript gives errors:
"SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" for use of "\\"
after that, the whole thing does not make sense anymore I guess

Comment: Sorry, Used incorrect slashes. should have been forward slashes instead of backslashes. typo, not incorrect code. It should work now.

Comment: I use the corrected code and now get: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'outputvariable')

Comment: If you remove the `.text()` and replace URL with your url, what is the value of outputVariable?

Comment: Same error. It seems like it does not do anything with the async part...
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'outputvariable')

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use the axios instead of the fetch.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const response = await axios('https://api2.online');

console.log(response.data);
```